# Helm - Can't install dependencies from private Github repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install packages from a private repository I've deployed using `chart-releases`, but I'm not being able to do it.

Here is what I've done:

1. I've created a new private repository, added a sample chart to it and ran the following commands:

```sh
helm package charts/* --destination .deploy
cr upload -o odelucca -r helm-charts -p .deploy -t $MY_TOKEN
```

2. I've created the `index.yaml` with the following command:

```sh
cr index --config .cr.yaml -t $MY_TOKEN
# My .cr.yaml file:
# owner: odelucca
# git-repo: helm-charts
# package-path: .deploy
# index-path: index.yaml
# charts-repo: https://github.com/odelucca/helm-charts/
```

3. I've commit the `index.yaml` to the repo
4. I've added the remote helm repo with the following command:

```sh
helm repo add helm-charts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/odelucca/helm-charts/master --username $MY_EMAIL --password $MY_TOKEN
```

5. The repo was added, then I've added the following dependency to a local chart:

```yaml
dependencies:
- name: serverless-common
  version: 1.0.0
  repository: "@helm-charts"
```

6. Now, I've tried to run the following:

```sh
helm dep update
```

7. I get the following errors:

```
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Unable to get an update from the "local" chart repository (http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts):
        Get http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts/index.yaml: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8879: connect: connection refused
...Successfully got an update from the "helm-charts" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete.
Saving 1 charts
Downloading serverless-common from repo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/odelucca/helm-charts/master
Save error occurred:  could not download https://github.com/odelucca/helm-charts/releases/download/serverless-common-1.0.0/serverless-common-1.0.0.tgz: Failed to fetch https://github.com/odelucca/helm-charts/releases/download/serverless-common-1.0.0/serverless-common-1.0.0.tgz : 404 Not Found
Deleting newly downloaded charts, restoring pre-update state
Error: could not download https://github.com/odelucca/helm-charts/releases/download/serverless-common-1.0.0/serverless-common-1.0.0.tgz: Failed to fetch https://github.com/odelucca/helm-charts/releases/download/serverless-common-1.0.0/serverless-common-1.0.0.tgz : 404 Not Found
```

Anyone can help me? I've tried a lot of different approaches, and none of them fix it

Comment: could you fix this ? work around ? anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the repository config file?
You should have something like this:

`vim ${HOEM}/.config/helm/repositories.yaml`

```
apiVersion: ""
generated: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
repositories:
- caFile: ""
  certFile: ""
  insecure_skip_tls_verify: false
  keyFile: ""
  name: helm-charts
  password: ""
  url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/odelucca/helm-charts/master"
  username: ""
```

Edit it and put your username and password to connect to your private registry.

For me, this works fine.

Maybe you also need to check your repo path.

You should be able to download with an URL like this:
`${repository}/${name}-${version}.tgz`